# How to ignore exceptions which are caused by McAfee scan

Tags: c#, asp.net

Every morning, we use McAfee to scan our web site. It will cause a lot of exceptions. ex.Invalid viewstate and Input string was not in a correct format.
In our code, we collect all exceptions in global.asax. Is there a way to ignore those exceptions caused by Mcafee?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of these scans is to see how your site reacts to these malformed requests.  Simply ignoring is *not* doing it right.  Raising exceptions (and handling them) is the correct thing to do.  Logging them is the correct thing to do.

In other words, everything is working fine and correctly.  Don't worry about dirty-looking logs, that's what they're for.

Comment: But sometime we cannot handle all exceptions.ex. invalid viewstate or below exception:System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData...
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this check is done from the same machine, so a simple ip check can show you if the requests coming from McAfee and then you ignore them. You can get the ip using the:

```
Request.UserHostAddress()
```

or

```
Context.Request.ServerVariables ["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Comment: I think McAfee IPs are changing all the time. I don't think this is a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanY You think - or you know ? Just check it out, they are a range of ip, you can even find google ip that are more than you can imaging. Other posible solution is to read the browser id data, possible say that is mcafee

Comment: @SeanY May I ask you what is the cost of this mcafee service ?